# send heartbeat gcm?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, heartbeat

I develop android app use GCM, i want to send heartbeat for every 5 minutes at once, i create it when service is run,these are my codes,

```
public class sendHeartbeat extends Service{
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");  
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new syncGetHeartbeat().execute();
            Log.d("send hearbeat","send hearrrrrrrbeat");

            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 260000);
        }
    };


    class syncGetHeartbeat extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> { 
       @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
            try {                       
                String varId="naengoland";
                String url = "http://mydomain.com/gcmserver/getHeartbeat.php?id="+varId; 
                getRequestJSON(url);

                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), "service get hertbeat "+ e.toString());
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {

        }
    }

    public String getRequestJSON(String Url){
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Url);
        try{
          client.execute(request);
        }catch(Exception ex){
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I successfully send the heartbeat for every 5 minutes, but the problem is my app running slowly and consume battery a lot, is there any way to send heartbeat beside doing my way?
i mean,the better method than my method.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `TimerTask` provides better performance than using Thread [(ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605403/timertask-vs-thread-sleep-vs-handler-postdelayed-most-accurate-to-call-functio).. However `TimerTask` isn't good in handling multiple threads at the same time which isn't a concern in your case because you are doing one task repeatedly.

here is the code for Timer:

first initialize a `Timer`:

```
private Timer timer;
```

in `onCreate`:

```
timer = new Timer();
```

then within `onStart`:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new syncGetHeartbeat().execute();
            Log.d("send hearbeat","send hearrrrrrrbeat");

        }
    }, 0, 300000); //means start at 0 second and each 5 mins (300000 ms) run the task
```

I'm not sure if there is another solution that has better performance however this is absolutely better than running thread in a fixed rate.