# Correct way to implement backgroundoperation in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask, timertask

In my app i need following functions and i'm not sure if i should use service, threads, asynctasks etc...

I got an activity where the user can control a "background" operation.

The background operation sends a mock_location to to system every 1sec.
Another background operation changes the location every 30sec.

In the activity and from another service/thread i want to be able to start/stop this operation and to send new data (position) to the background operation while it is running.

Atm i got a Service which is getting all the data from the activity and from this service i start timertasks that change the position. The service is controlling the timertasks.

My problem: 
This way is much to memory and power consuming so i'm wondering if there is a better solution...

Comment: Please Check this link i guess it may helps you :)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605403/timertask-vs-thread-sleep-vs-handler-postdelayed-most-accurate-to-call-functio

Comment: Ty! Should i keep a Service for processing the data from the activity and start the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: Yes that's better way to implement as per my conceren :)

Comment: When i did some stress tests on my app i even got the cellphone crashed with several: Out of memory: Heap Size=524288KB, Allocated=519900KB, Limit=196608KB, Proc Limit=524288KB
in several processes. Do you have an idea what could cause this heavy kind of memory usage? I don't have any bitmaps in my code - just TimerTasks and location based functions (providers, locations,...)

Comment: Can you please post your error on the post so i can help you on it

Comment: The problem is there are many errors - none is tagged to my app - i think they are all related to out of memory - i uploaded a part of the logcat dump: http://drive-zone.info/logcatdump.txt

Comment: Can you please send me your application package name so it's better for me which errors are belongs to yours as per the catlog i seen some issues are related to os not yours

Comment: I attached it to the top of the log - don't want to have my package name in public ;)

Comment: If you are not providing your packagename so how can i identify is that issues belongs to ur app? and as per my concern most of the issues belongs to os and one is belongs to this application de.appsmadeingermany.gpsfakelocation