# Repeat method in short time interval

Tags: java, android, performance, time

I have a activity and I have to update the Views (like Images) every second. I tried a  few different methods which I found to implement the same thing. But which of the method is most efficient and reduces memory leak?

Here are the different methods -

Method 1

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //DO SOMETHING
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Method 2

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Method 3

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Which one should I use? I am asking this question because I'm updating my GUI in very short interval of time.

Comment: Are you truly "updating" the displayed data, or are you animating something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Context

Take into account the fact the Android uses it's own implementation of java.

> There is no Java Virtual Machine in the Android platform. Java
>   bytecode is not executed. Instead Java classes are compiled into a
>   proprietary bytecode format and run on Dalvik, a specialized virtual
>   machine (VM) designed specifically for Android. Unlike Java VMs, which
>   are stack machines, the Dalvik VM is a register-based architecture.

[Comparison of Java and Android API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API)

So what holds true for the java virtual machine may not necessarily reflect on Android's implementation.

As a rule of thumbs it's better to use whatever the Android API makes available.

#### Solution

**I recommend using the Handler**.
Especially if you want to update views.

Even the [official Android tutorials](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)  recommends :

> To move data from a background thread to the UI thread, use a Handler
>   that's running on the UI thread.

From the start **Timer gets excluded**.

> There are some disadvantages of using Timer It creates only single
>   thread to execute the tasks and if a task takes too long to run, other
>   tasks suffer. It does not handle exceptions thrown by tasks and thread
>   just terminates, which affects other scheduled tasks and they are
>   never run

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18606091/4807777).

And from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> *A ThreadPoolExecutor (i.e. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor)*  is preferable to Timer when multiple worker threads are needed, or when
>   the additional flexibility or capabilities of ThreadPoolExecutor
>   (which this class extends) are required.

When using the Handler **i recommend reading through [this tutorial](https://techblog.badoo.com/blog/2014/08/28/android-handler-memory-leaks) if you want to avoid memory leaks**.

If it wasn't the case of an UI update a ThreadPoolExecutor would have been better [because](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) they provide improved performance when executing large numbers of  asynchronous tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update values or images on your screen you should use the first method. I solved the same issue by using first method.

**Method 1**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //DO SOMETHING
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

**Alternative**

```
Thread t = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           //update here (images or other values)
                        }
                    });
                }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
};
```