# how do i get a functon to repeat in java

Tags: java, multithreading, class, timer

I am making a slapjack game where the deck will need to give to cards to the slapzone every 5 seconds and flip the image for 2 seconds before turning the picture back over. I know i will have to use a thread, but i can't figure out how to say repeat every 5 seconds i know the repeating part will take a for loop though.

**Code:**

```
public void run ()
{
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();     
    while (thisThread == myThread)         
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < numcards ; i++)
            {
                deck.giveslapZone(slap1); 
            }

            myThread = null;                // kills the thread 
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
            System.out.println(ie.getMessage());    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop and `Thread.sleep(5000)` in it

Comment: Setting `myThread` to null does not 'kill the thread'. It exits the outer loop. They both appear quite pointless.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your class implements Runnable and then declare Thread thread = new Thread(this); and then:
for eg.

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numcards; i++)
            {
                deck.giveslapZone(slap1); 
            }
            thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
            System.out.println(ie.getMessage());    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) if you believe this may grow past a trivial implementation.  A Scheduler thread would handle multiple threads and exceptions in a much smoother manner.

See the example in...

[TimerTask vs Thread.sleep vs Handler postDelayed - most accurate to call function every N milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605403/timertask-vs-thread-sleep-vs-handler-postdelayed-most-accurate-to-call-functio/18606091#18606091)