# how to disable button for some for example 2 minutes in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want complete code to disable a `Button` for some time for example **2 minutes** in Android Studio. Thank you for help.

```
 protected void onclick(View v){

    bwasta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDes);
    new CountDownTimer(10000, 10) { //Set Timer for 10 seconds
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            bwasta.setEnabled(true);
            bwasta.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out.

```
Button bwasta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDes);

bwasta.setEnabled(false);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2*
                             60*
                            1000);//min secs millisecs
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bwasta.setEnabled(true);

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

### DO NOT RELY ON `Thread.sleep()`

Actually, there is already a Question and an Answer on SO regarding the **inaccuracy** of `Thread.sleep()`(as per the OP's experience) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605403/timertask-vs-thread-sleep-vs-handler-postdelayed-most-accurate-to-call-functio).

The answer then favors the accuracy of a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` using the `schedule()` method.

Do the following:

```
Button bwasta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDes);

bwasta.setEnabled(false);

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
exec.schedule(new new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                bwasta.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
    }
}, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mTime) function to achieve this

```
Button bwasta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDes);

bwasta.setEnabled(false);

bwasta.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    bwasta.setEnabled(true);
  }
}, 2*60*1000);
```

Comment: It would sleep for an hour instead of 2 minutes.